# Can I make transactions on the user's behalf using some exchange API (Binance, Coinbase etc.)?

Tags: binance, coinbase-api, binance-api-client

I've read the Binance API documentation but it's still not clear to me whether it allows for a 3rd party app to initiate a payment, and then just have the user confirm it.

For example, I want to build an application which would allow the user to send tokens to a previously defined address, but most of my user base won't have MetaMask or a hardware wallet (so it's not that straightforward like with using ethers.js or web3.js), they'll mostly keep their tokens on an exchange.

Also, if this can't be done through Binance, is there another exchnge that would enable this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `withdraw` endpoint.

Docs: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#withdraw-user_data

Comment: After more digging, I found this - https://developers.binance.com/docs/binance-pay/introduction. It seems that they offer oAuth and permissions to 3rd party apps. Thank you for the help though.